# Scale images in each row to fill it 100% with JavaScript or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a simple responsive gallery.
[Code pen here](http://codepen.io/ztm/pen/JYrJXr)

There only a simple CSS setting for images now:

```
img {
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

I want my gallery rows to be 100% in width and scale the image heights in each row accordingly keeping the aspect ratio.

The scenario is something like this:
On window load and resize:
1. Wrap each row into #div
2. Calculate image height for each row (overriding the initial fixed value)

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkOqT.png)

I was trying to find a pure CSS way, but looks like I can not get away without some JavaScript here.

---

EDIT: I was able to make this with some  jQUery "mad skills":
codepen.io/ztm/pen/NGwaEL

```
    $(document).ready(cascade);
    $(window).on('resize',cascade);

    function cascade() {
     $('img').css({ 'height': 150 + "px" });
    var wdth = $(".box").width();

    var img_width = 0;
    $('img').each(function() {
        img_width += $(this).outerWidth( true );

          if(img_width < wdth){
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.result').html('Ratio: '+wdth/img_width);
        }
    });

    var ratio = (wdth-24)/img_width;
    $('img').css({ 'height': 150*ratio + "px" });
    }
```

It calculates a single row of image with initial height.

And so far the best solution to my problem I found was this:
miromannino.com/projects/justified-gallery/comment-page-4/

Comment: this isn't possible.  You will lose aspect ratio to get them to fit width wise.  In you desired result, the images increase in width but the heights don't change

Comment: in his desired results, the heights change @JacobRaccuia

Comment: @Jacob - the heights do change for each row

Comment: The heights do change, but still this isn't possible. You would never have a perfect match. Filling the available width would make each image grow in height in a different amount, since they have different ratios.

Comment: @LcSalazar, It is possible, take a row width divided by total width of images in the row - and you will get a ratio. Multiply this ration by each image width and images will fill the row width.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your 'Desired result' link, it looks to me like you are wanting a Google+/Google Photos style gallery layout.  In this style of gallery, images are added to a row until they fit the width of the row and then a new row is started.

The reason you can't get away with just css is that some trickery is needed to get images of various sizes to fit perfectly into the width of each row.  The simplest solution to this is to add images until they exceed the width of the row, then crop all those images down to fit the row perfectly, that method is outlined in detail with jQuery and CSS here: [Google+ Style Image Gallery](http://www.techbits.de/2011/10/25/building-a-google-plus-inspired-image-gallery/)

There are other methods you can use, like adding images until it is a certain percentage under the width of the row then scaling up the size of the images on that row so they fit perfectly, but the idea remains the same: add images until they are within a range of their parent container, then grow or shrink the images to make them the exact width.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for this solution. Works fine in Chrome.

```
  [1]: http://codepen.io/sridharspeaks/pen/meBwNN
```

Answer (score -1):

You may look at the [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) or [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugins that could help you with this.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to learn to do things from scratch and avoid plugins for this task